# Is there a notion of polynomial ring in "one half variable"?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, functors

Let $C$ be the category of commutative rings.

> Is there a functor $F :C \to C$ such that $F(F(R)) \cong R[X]$ for every commutative ring $R$ ?

(Here, we may assume those isomorphisms to be natural in $R$, if needed).

I tried to see what $F(\mathbb Z)$ or $F(k)$ (for a field $k$) should be, but I cannot come up with a contradiction to disprove the existence of $F$. On the other hand, I tried to build such an $F$, without success (e.g. try to consider some extension of  $\mathbb Z[X_r : r \in R] / (X_{a+b} - X_a - X_b, X_{ab} - X_a X_b)$...).

Comment: I would expect that if such a thing exists it is not any remotely natural construction but instead some crazy thing you can construct assuming global choice because merely being a functor is a relatively weak condition.

Comment: What if you also assume $F$ preserves limits and filtered colimits ?

Comment: @uno : what would be your ideas in that case?

Comment: Now asked on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/361976/84923